# Disabling introduction of Skolem function in linear arithmetic proof

Tags: z3

Given the following SMT2 script:

```
(set-option :produce-proofs true)
(set-logic AUFLIRA)
(declare-sort Complex$ 0)
(declare-fun r$ () Real)
(declare-fun s$ () Complex$)
(declare-fun re$ (Complex$) Real)
(declare-fun norm$ (Complex$) Real)
(assert (! (not (=> (and (forall ((?v0 Complex$)) (<= (ite (< (re$ ?v0) 0.0) (- (re$ ?v0)) (re$ ?v0)) (norm$ ?v0))) (<= (norm$ s$) r$)) (<= (ite (< (re$ s$) 0.0) (- (re$ s$)) (re$ s$)) (+ r$ 1.0)))) :named a0))
(check-sat)
(get-proof)
```

Z3 (unstable version) produces a proof that contains a Skolem function "norm$0". This function is introduced in a rewrite step:

```
(ALL v0. (if 0 <= Re v0 then Re v0 else - 1 * Re v0) <= cmod v0) =
((ALL v0. cmod v0 = (if 0 <= Re v0 then Re v0 else - 1 * Re v0) + norm_0 v0) & (ALL v0. 0 <= norm_0 v0))
```

Can this behavior be suppressed by a command-line switch? That is, is there an option such that Z3 produces a proof without such a Skolem function? This should, in principle, be possible, as Z3 version 3.2 finds a proof that does not require a Skolem function.

Answer (score 0):

The skolem constant is introduced by the MBQI (model-based quantifier instantiation) module. This is probably the "new part" that makes you see the different behavior.
MBQI is much more powerful than the pattern-based quantifier instantiation.
For your example, however, the pattern-based quantifier instantiation strategy works. So you can try this.

In other words run Z3 as follows to suppress MBQI:

z3 skolem-example.smt2 smt.mbqi=false auto-config=false